# Two for loops for nested lists in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a list

```
mylist=[["ball1","boy2"], ["ball1","boy3"], ["ball2","boy2"]]
```

How can I in first for loop print "ball1" and in second loop print "boy2"?

I tried:

```
for l1 in list:
    print(l1[0])
    for l1 in list:
        print(l1[1])
```

But it doesnt work. What is wrong with that double loop?

Comment: Can you post code that is runnable and also try not to override the 'list' builtin function

Comment: What are `element` and `element2`?

Comment: Please update your question with your desired output. `it doesnt work` is not a description of the fault.

Comment: @Samwise I changed my code somewhat

Comment: @quamrana First print function should give "ball1", second print "boy2".

Comment: Please update your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68653027/edit) with your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
mylist=[["ball1","boy2"], ["ball1","boy3"], ["ball2","boy2"]]
for l1 in mylist:
    for i in l1:
        print(i)
```

and dont use the reserved keyword '**list**' for variable name.

Comment: I changed some my code, for first print I want to obtain "ball1", for second print "boy2" etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `ball1`, `boy2`, `element2`, etc are things you've actually defined elsewhere in your code; if they aren't this won't run, but I think this loop is roughly what you're trying to do:

```
my_list = [[ball1, boy2], [ball1, boy3], [ball2, boy2]]
elements = element, element2

for i in range(len(elements)):
    for keys in my_list:
        elements[i].send_keys(keys[i])
```

i.e. we want to iterate first over the range of 2 elements, and within that loop, iterate over `my_list` (never name a variable `list`, it overrides the builtin name) and send the key that corresponds to the element.

In response to your edit, if you're just trying to print strings in a list of lists where you go in order of the sublists, the easy solution is to use `zip` along with the `*` operator to transpose the lists:

```
>>> my_list = [["ball1", "boy2"], ["ball1", "boy3"], ["ball2", "boy2"]]
>>> for keys in zip(*my_list):
...     for key in keys:
...         print(key)
...
ball1
ball1
ball2
boy2
boy3
boy2
```

Comment: I use print as example function. What if there was other function like send_keys?

Comment: What if there was?  I don't know enough about the function to tell you if it'd work any differently from `print`.  Your original example made it look like it was a method on some other set of objects, but you didn't explain how those objects relate to your list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you wanna list for each different ball the list of boys.
You can create a `dict` to each ball'X:

```py
balls = {}
for element in mylist:
    ball = element[0]
    boy = element[1]
    if ball not in balls:
        balls[ball]=[boy]
    else: 
        balls[ball].append(boy)
```

And then `print(balls)` to see the generated dictionary, **or** get our personal print like this:

```py
for ball in balls:
   print (ball,':'):
   for boy in balls[ball]:
       print('\t',boy)
```

Result:

```
ball1 :
     boy2
     boy3
ball2 :
     boy2
```

Comment: If that's not what you want, update your question with an full expected output, then I'll fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print `"ball1"`, then `"boy2"` you can just print the first sub list:

```py
mylist=[["ball1","boy2"], ["ball1","boy3"], ["ball2","boy2"]]
for l1 in mylist[0]:
    print(l1)
```